# How to change marker of google maps to a custom color in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers

Basically what I have is a constant of Color(0xFF3B7097) and I want to change the default color of marker in google maps to it. I dont want to use the default colors variable in BitmapDescriptor is their any other way?

BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(Color(0xFF3B7097)),

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by using asset image:

```
icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5), 'assets/markers/Queen-blue.png')
```